# how do I sort the value axis of an SSRS line chart based on the value of another column?

Tags: reporting-services

how do I sort the value axis of an SSRS line chart based on the value of another column? e.g 20,10,40,30 rather than 40,30,20,10 (SSRS default sort order).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Chart properties > Sorting**. Here you can add a expression or a field which determies the sort order. In the expression you can write another field. Fir exampla your chart axis is the field `Sales` then you can sort it after another field called `Region` from `Z to A`.